# pathForResource yields erratic null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have some problems adding my shader-glsl files from one xcode project to another. I'm completely confused at this moment, since I can't make a path to files I simply drag into xcode.
I have checked spelling, "show in finder" many times and still have the problem...

Here's my example of files I added to xCode, I didn't even put them into sub-directories to rule out any problems with those:
    [image: Screenshot]

Now my code:

```
    NSLog(@"Filepath of Tools-image: %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tools" ofType:@"png"]);
    NSLog(@"Filepath of mo-tut is: %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mo" ofType:@"tut"]);
    NSLog(@"Filepath of FragShader-fsh is: %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fragshader" ofType:@"fsh"]);
```

At run-time I get this output:

```
2011-07-02 02:03:33.516 windowconfig[16192:707] Filepath of Tools-image: /var/mobile/Applications/BC82AD2C-B8B9-4751-80A2-31EC5ACEC9C2/windowconfig.app/tools.png
2011-07-02 02:03:33.526 windowconfig[16192:707] Filepath of mo-tut is: /var/mobile/Applications/BC82AD2C-B8B9-4751-80A2-31EC5ACEC9C2/windowconfig.app/mo.tut
2011-07-02 02:03:33.531 windowconfig[16192:707] Filepath of FragShader-fsh is: (null)
```

Please, does anyone have an idea on this?

EDIT: "tools.png" currently is an icon I use on a tab-bar, its in a subfolder in resources and was just a test for comparison. In case you guys wonder why I didn't open the path to the other file in the screenshot.

EDIT2: I used "Clean" like crazy in the last two hours. "fragshader.fsh" appearently doesn't get copied to the "windowconfig.app" bundle even though I added it to the project in the same way I added "mo.tut" and this one is in the bundle package. How can I ensure it gets copied?

EDIT3: Target Membership is checked in the Inspector for both files, still teh shader isn't copied.

**Solution:**

Under Target-Build Phases the file wasn't in the "copy files to bundle" list.
I manually added it, but still its strange it wasn't added automatically after I added the file to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure that fragshader.fsh is in a copy files step? (i.e. made sure it's actually present in the resulting app bundle).

Comment: Well fragshader is not included in "windowconfig.app" if I open the bundle under "~/Library/Xcode/DerivedData/....". 
"mo.tut" is, even though I added them in the exact same way to Xcode. How can I make sure it gets copied, and what could be a reason it didn't get into the copy files step?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html or similar could be helpful :)